# Angular UI design options

Tags: angular, design-patterns, components

I am very new to Angular and need some recommendations on how to design this use case.

Screen 1 - Provide multiple text boxes fr user to enter data

Screen 2  - Provide search results based on the data entered

Question 1-
I was thinking to have 2 html components tied to the same component.ts file. Is this a good design to have? Or does it make sense to have 2 different components altogether.

Question 2-
Is it possible to write a class like SearchCriteria which includes all the attributes to be included in the UI so that in future if the search criteria changes we have minimal changes or are there any well known design patterns within Angular to implement search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

**Question 1**

*I was thinking to have 2 html components tied to the same component.ts file. Is this a good design to have? Or does it make sense to have 2 different components altogether.*

- In Angular, there is only one template for every component class. Since Angular uses component based concept, you will need to create a tree of components from a root component for you to use multiple templates. See the structure for reference:

[image]

**Question 2**

*Is it possible to write a class like SearchCriteria which includes all the attributes to be included in the UI so that in future if the search criteria changes we have minimal changes or are there any well known design patterns within Angular to implement search.*

Yes it is possible. You can create a custom search class component. You will need to import that component to other component for you to use it. In your case, you can create a custom pipe for search functionality.

For references:

- [Angular Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)
- [Sample Search Pipe](https://www.codementor.io/chintankotadiya/angular-4-6-filter-search-custom-pipe-td46o91qg)

Comment: Welcome, I hope this helps!